# New files on Visual Studio are marked as Miscellaneous

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file

I added simple class file to the project and it marked as Miscellaneous.

[image]

Usually the following actions helped me in this case:
- Unload and Reload a projects
- Close solution, delete .vs file and reload solution

But it didn't help me now.
I used Build Loging tool to see what's wrong and I found the next error:

[image]

Comment: Did you add it to the *solution* or did you add it to a *project* within that solution?

Comment: To the project under solution

Comment: Based on my search, you can try clean and build solution to check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in .csproj file for problem solution.

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
```

I removed it and was loaded successfully.